# How to get the exactly instance of DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a multiples `db contexts` in a Web Application of Visual Studio 2015, and i am doing a `middleware` to saves changes in all db contexts.

But i am having problems because in the Invoke Method call of the `middleware` i have an instance of my `MembershipDbContext` and in the action when i updating the entity have another.

Then the `SaveChanges()` are not doing anything because the instance have not changes in the stack trace.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please edit your question and add some of your code, preferably demonstrating how you are using the different contexts. It is very hard to help if there is no code to refer to. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the Help section

Comment: You should concider taking your code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ and showing your code there. Looks like your architecture needs revising, if you face such problems.

Comment: @raderick The author of this question indicates a specific problem with their code/software, which would be off-topic at Code Review (due to malfunctioning/broken code). See [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)